# failed to create task or type resourceexists

Tags: ant

I am using

```
<resourceexists>
  <file file="${file}"/>
</resourceexists>
```

but getting an error in ant 1.8.2 as follows :

upgrade.xml:44: Problem: failed to create task or type resourceexists 
Cause: The name is undefined. Action: Check the spelling. 
Action: Check that any custom tasks/types have been declared. 
Action: Check that any / declarations have taken place.

What may be the reason?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `<resourceexists/>` is a `<condition/>` nested task. You should use is in this way:

```
<project name="resourcetest" default="test">
    <target name="test">
        <condition property="is.resource.exists" value="true" else="false">
            <resourceexists>
                <file file="C:\ac.txt"/>
            </resourceexists>
        </condition>
        <echo>Does file C:\ac.txt exists? ${is.resource.exists}</echo>
    </target>
</project>
```